# Adding contents of a DataViewGrid to access - VB

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datagridview

I've got quite the frustrating issue! My VB code below is intended to transfer the records in a DataGridView to an Access database. Let's say, for example, the gridview has three records

```
Name|House|Age
John|L|1
Rick|B|12
Fred|A|20
```

The 'name|house|age' is the header of the GridView, whilst the three records make up the body. In my logic below, I get, in the Access database, John's record three times (i.e., instead of having John, Rick and Fred, I just have the exact same John, L, 1 three times).

I'm sure this is a small logic error that I've overlooked - so a fresh perspective and pair of eyes would be great. I've only included what I think to be the source of the problem, but happy to include more source if the problem potentially lies outside of this.

I appreciate your help!

```
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =Jack.mdb")
                Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO students(StuName,House,Age) VALUES (@StuName,@House,@Age)", con)
                Dim studentName As String
                Dim studentHouse As String
            Dim studentAge As String
            con.Open()

            For x As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                studentName = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value
                studentHouse = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Value
                studentAge = DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(2).Value


                Try
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StuName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = studentName
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@House", SqlDbType.Text).Value = studentHouse
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", SqlDbType.Text).Value = studentAge
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next x
                con.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep adding parameters over and over.  Try clearing them at the beginning of the loop:

```
For x As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
  cmd.Parameters.Clear()
```

and avoid empty Try-Catches.  You are ignoring problems in your code when you do that.  For one thing, the "Age" field probably shouldn't be a text field.

Since you are using the OleDb library, your parameters should probably use the OleDbType instead of the SqlDbType.

Comment: Worked a charm! Lifesaver!